# How to store and then execute linq2db query?

Tags: c#, .net-core, linq2db

I'm very new to C#. In other languages I'm used to work with DB in a way "prepare, then execute statement with needed parameters", so I could pass prepared query to function and do all such things.
Now I'm trying to solve this task: get almost identicaly result sets from different databases in different contexts. Like you have "files" table with files metadata and in one DB it does have "file_priority" field, and in other DB it does have "file_description" field and so on, but most fields are common and processing logic are almost same.

So I wanted to prepare query in outer code and pass it along with needed param values to data-processing function (or class).

I can't find any example of executing (pass param values to query) linq2db query.

==========UPD============

Ok, example. Let's talk about Perl.

```perl
package main1;
use FileProcessor;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq[ SELECT name, extension, file_priority FROM files WHERE file_id = ? ]);

my $processor = new FileProcessor(query => $sth);
my $file_id = $ENV{file_id};
my $file_data = $processor->get_file(id => $file_id);

package main2;
use FileProcessor;

my $sth = $dbh->prepare(qq[ SELECT name, extension, file_description FROM files WHERE file_id = ? ]); # preparing query

my $processor = new FileProcessor(query => $sth);
my $file_id = $ENV{file_id};
my $file_data = $processor->get_file(id => $file_id);

package FileProcessor;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {@_};
    bless $self, $class;
}

sub get_file {
    my $self = shift;
    my %params = @_;
    $self->{query}->execute($params{$file_id}); #passing params to query
    my $file_data = $self->{query}->fetchrow_hashref; # fetching result from DB
# do something with file data
# ...
    return $file_data;
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what exactly you're looking for. Could you provide an attempt for what you're trying to do? And/or perhaps provide an example in SQL that explains how you want it to be reusable?

Comment: See edited post.

Answer (score 1):

`linq2db` will not give you preparation step. But you can run raw query via a lot of extensions:

```cs
db.Query<File>("SELECT name, extension, file_priority FROM files WHERE file_id = @fileid", 
   new DataPamater("@fileid", id));
```

```cs
db.Query<File>("SELECT name, extension, file_priority FROM files WHERE file_id = @fileid", 
   new { fileid = id });
```

It is not typical for `linq2db` to do that in such way, because it supports LINQ queries and parameters will be created automatically:

```cs
var id = 1;
var query = 
   from f in db.GetTable<File>()
   where f.file_id = id
   select new File
   {
      name = f.name,
      extension = f.extension,
      file_priority = f.file_priority
   };

var file = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I did some research further. Isn't CompiledQuery.Compile() is what I'm looking for?

Comment: No, it is not related. Actually why do you need prepared query?

Comment: I... want to pass query to service. From outside. And that service will execute it with given parameters.

Comment: So, first example is what you need.

Comment: But it is raw SQL. And if I want LINQ, why not to use CompiledQuery.Compile()?

Comment: Compiled query is for static query caching. Not for sending via network. Crete question issue in `linq2db` github repository with explanation what you are trying to achieve and we will try to help you. SO not for discussions.